# How do you enable Autoprefixer CSS Grid translations in create-react-app without using control comments?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, postcss, autoprefixer

I am trying to enable Autoprefixer Grid translations in a Create React App application.

**I do not want to eject**.

I'm also using a CSS-in-JS solution that makes it impossible to add comments to the CSS. So the `/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */` control comment method is not possible.

Is it still possible to enable grid translations without ejecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of asking, it was not possible. It is now though.

If you apply an `AUTOPREFIXER_GRID = autoplace` environment variable when you are compiling your code, you can enable grid translations without using control comments.

You can read about how to do this in the [Autoprefixer documentation](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#environment-variables).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the official documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/post-processing-css/):

> [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) prefixing is disabled by default, but it will **not**
>   strip manual prefixing. If you'd like to opt-in to CSS Grid prefixing,
>   [first familiarize yourself about its limitations](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#does-autoprefixer-polyfill-grid-layout-for-ie).
>
> To enable CSS Grid prefixing, add `/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */`
>   to the top of your CSS file.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update my question and provide the answer. While not incorrect, I already knew about the `/* autoprefixer grid: autoplace */` thing. My issue was that I was using a CSS-in-JS solution and I needed to be able to turn on CSS Grid translations without using control comments. At the time of asking this, it was not possible to do what I wanted.